# Prolog: Grouping AND OR Statements in rules

Tags: prolog

If I have a logical statement:
If (A or C) and (B or D) then E.
How do i turn this into a prolog rule?

Can they be grouped using brackets such as:
    E :- (A;C),(B;D).

Comment: Try and put some code. Can you?

Comment: @WedaPashi: It is not necessary here.

Comment: To Shawn: your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @Shawn, you are dealing with disjunctions in Prolog and yes it is correct. You can have a look at this basic tutorial: http://voidexception.weebly.com/disjunctions.html Hope it helps.